# Growth of apparent horizons and null convergence condition

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, event-horizon

An apparent horion ( S. W. Hawking & G. F. R. Ellis (1975). *The large scale structure of space-time*.) in General Relativity is a surface where all null vectors are pointing "inwards", i.e. it is the location of a marginally outer trapped surface (for a review see [Thornburg, Jonathan; Living Rev.Rel. 10 (2007) 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0512169)). It is well known (see Hawking and Ellis) that if the Null Convergence Condition

\begin{equation}
R_{ab}k^ak^b\geq0 \qquad \forall k^a \qquad s.t. \qquad k^ak_a=0
\end{equation}

holds everywhere in a spacetime, then black hole (i.e. event) horizons can only grow in size, and not shrink. Does a similar statement hold for apparent horizons?